# toggle the colors of two arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code that looks like this,  https://jsfiddle.net/mdwxbppd/

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span><br />
<span class="col-md-12" style="height: 1px; font-family: 'Passion One', cursive; bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0.01em;">
    <h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">
        {{ post.get_vote_count }}
    </h4>
</span><br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

I'm trying to achieve the buttons to toggle the color when each one is clicked. I tried it, but whenever I refresh the page the color goes back to the original one when it should remain untill I click the other arrow(since they toggle). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's what I tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.glyphicon').click(function(){
        $('.glyphicon').css('color', '#333');
        $(this).css('color', '#10fd01');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add your JS code to the snippet so we can see what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MitchKarajohn sure thing

Comment: "whenever I refresh the page the color goes back to the original"  Web pages don't know anything about what happened in previous sessions. If you need to maintain state across page reloads, you need to store that state somewhere (in cookies or localStorage for example) and read it again on page load.

Comment: @DanielBeck hmm that sounds like a lot of work,,,I'm still a beginner....do you mean I need to save that in models.py as a field(I'm using django) and use that with js possibly?

Comment: I don't really speak django; I believe models.py describes your database structure? In a server db would be another way to do this, yes.  (For a shared database you'll need to store it separately per user, of course.)

Comment: hmm...ok I should use cookies like someone here suggested probably....I'm sorry but can you show me how I can use cookie if you don't mind...if you don't want to that's cool too;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, that is what you are looking for, but if it is, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie("arrow1")){
         //$('#arrow1').toggleClass... or whatever
    }
    $('span.glyphicon').click(function(e){
        $.cookie(e.target.id, true);
        //e.target.toggle class, e.target.style.color =... or whatever
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah but with this when I refresh the page, the color goes back to the original state

Comment: If you need to save state of arrows, may you can use cookies

Comment: Done. Try with it  , hope its help :D

Comment: ok thanks I didn't down vote your answer btw...I appreciate your answer

Comment: The downvote was mine: as originally written the answer was functionally  identical to the code in the question.  Removed the downvote after the edit.

Comment: Using a pure client-side solution like localStorage (or sessionStorage, depending on how persistent the state should be stored) ought to be enough. No need for cookies (which are also sent to the server on each page load). But if you do anything with this information (on the server), you might also store it there and get it from there using an ajax request.